# Run command in tmux and update the status bar

Tags: command-line, terminal, tmux

I wrote a simple shell script that will show IP every 15 sec (it checks for VPN basically )...
I wanted to add that in my status bar and I did it with `#()` but it just shows the result once!

and I look up the manual for that and under the format section it said:

> In addition, the last line of a shell command's output may be
> inserted using ‘#()’.  For example, ‘#(uptime)’ will insert the
> system's uptime.  When constructing formats, tmux does not wait for
> ‘#()’ commands to finish; instead, the previous result from running
> the same command is used, or a placeholder if the command has not
> been run before.  If the command hasn't exited, the most recent
> line of output will be used, but the status line will not be
> updated more than once a second.  Commands are executed with the
> tmux global environment set (see the GLOBAL AND SESSION ENVIRONMENT
> section).

i just wanted to know is there any other way to run script and update its result on status bat?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your script's output in a file (say, add a `> ~/.ip` instead of wherever your script currently outputs from) and use `#(cat ~/.ip)` in your tmux' status-right, that way instead of running said script once and reading one line from a loop, tmux will read your script's output from a file where it is changing dynamically. I did similar thing with `ti` script for myself - except my creation wraps a command i give to it interactively. Still, the "indicator" itself is a file.

Said `ti` script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
if [[ -f ~/.tistop ]]
then
rm ~/.tistop
rm ~/.ti
exit
else
bash -c "$*" >> ~/.ti; sleep 2
fi
done &
```